# FileInputStream throws filenotfound exception even though uri fetches correct path

Tags: java, android

This is my code:

*In the code below, I am choosing a file and getting its data and storing it as uri*:

```
Uri uri = null;
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent data = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                data.setType("*/*");
                data = Intent.createChooser(data, "Choose a file");
                launch_activity.launch(data);
            }
        });

ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launch_activity = registerForActivityResult
            (new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                    new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                                try {
                                    Intent data = result.getData();
                                    if (data != null) {
                                        uri = data.getData();
                                    }
                             }
                        }
                    });
```

---

*Here I am fetching the file object from my uri*

```
File file;
try {
    file = new File(uri.getPath());
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
     fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file); //error occurs here
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

I keep getting this error when I execute the code:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/document:277030: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

What does it mean? How do I fix it?

**EDIT:** I have even added this line in my manifest:

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Also I have added this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But I still get `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Did you try "new File(uri.getPath())"? I think, this is what you need.

Comment: Okay, then it seems that you're uri is a relative path. Can you log this to check this? Try to convert the relative path to an absolute path with the Path library.

Comment: Ps: file.toPath() and path.toFile() can be useful for this.

Comment: I am sorry, `new File(uri.getPath())` is working. Now I am having a different issue. Please check my post